# Docker within Docker container not mapping .ssh volume

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

Im trying to map a volume from my main host machine, into a docker container, which then creates another docker container.

my first container is created as per the below:

```
docker run --rm -it \
-e JOB="release" \
-e LOG_FOLDER="$logDirectory" \
-v "$logDirectory":"$logDirectory" \
-e TEMP_FOLDER="$tempFolder" \
-v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
-v "$tempFolder":"$tempFolder" \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
release
```

The above works great, and when I /bin/bash into this container I can see that the .ssh folder has mapped and is showing the contents from my host machine.

But then when I try to create ANOTHER docker container within this one, using the below:

```
docker run --rm -it \
-e JOB=summary \
-e TEMP_FOLDER="$TEMP_FOLDER" \
-v "$TEMP_FOLDER":"$TEMP_FOLDER" \
-v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
summary /bin/bash
```

The container is created with no issues, but the .ssh folder content hasn't been mapped. However the TEMP_FOLDER has been mapped correctly and is showing the content from the host machine, I dont know why the .ssh folder isn't doing the same?

Is there a permission problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but the work around ive found is below, perhaps the root user was not the same across containers.

```
docker run --rm -it \
-e JOB="release" \
-e LOG_FOLDER="$logDirectory" \
-v "$logDirectory":"$logDirectory" \
-e TEMP_FOLDER="$tempFolder" \
-v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
-v ~/.ssh:/home/user/.ssh \
-v /home/user/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
-v "$tempFolder":"$tempFolder" \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
release
```

```
docker run --rm -it \
-e JOB=summary \
-e TEMP_FOLDER="$TEMP_FOLDER" \
-v "$TEMP_FOLDER":"$TEMP_FOLDER" \
-v /home/user/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
summary /bin/bash
```

Comment: The shell inside the container expands `~` before it gets passed up to the host, and the host Docker daemon always interprets the `-v` options (you cannot bind-mount container content into another container).  Also remember that you can bind-mount literally any host file in read-write mode (including `/etc/shadow` or `/etc/sudoers`), so be very very careful with quoting and security concerns in this mode.